# 1KHz Binary Counter: output stuck at 0000

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm trying to build a 1KHz binary counter in Verilog for use in an FPGA. I want to get it to work in a single .v file before separating each module into it's own file and getting practice in calling modules that way.

As far as I can see, I've set up the logic and the connections properly but after compiling/programming into the FPGA, my hex displays are just stuck at 0 instead of incrementing through.

Can someone please take a look and tell me where I might be going wrong?

Notes:

- The input CLK50 and the HEX(0-3) pins have been connected to their proper pins via Pin Assignment.

```
module IO_Test3(

    input                   CLK50,
    output [6:0]            HEX0,
    output [6:0]            HEX1,
    output [6:0]            HEX2,
    output [6:0]            HEX3
); 

    wire CLOCK1;
    wire count; 
    

    One_KHz_Clock clock(CLK50, CLOCK1);
    
    Counter_16B counter(CLOCK1, count);
    
    Display_Driver_SevenSeg display(CLOCK1,count,HEX0,HEX1,HEX2,HEX3);
    
endmodule 


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


module Display_Driver_SevenSeg(
    
    input                           CLOCK_1, // 1KHz clock
    input wire                      count,      //16 bit register
    output wire [6:0]           HEX0,
    output wire [6:0]           HEX1,
    output wire [6:0]           HEX2,
    output wire [6:0]           HEX3
);

    reg[15:0]       counter; 

    always@(*)
    begin
        counter <= count;
    end
    
seg7 Dig0(counter[3:0], HEX0);
seg7 Dig1(counter[7:4], HEX1);
seg7 Dig2(counter[11:8], HEX2);
seg7 Dig3(counter[15:12], HEX3);

endmodule


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module seg7(input [3:0] hex, output wire [6:0] segments);

reg[6:0] leds;

always @(*) begin
    case (hex)
            0: leds = 7'b0111111;
            1: leds = 7'b0000110;
            2: leds = 7'b1011011;
            3: leds = 7'b1001111;
            4: leds = 7'b1100110;
            5: leds = 7'b1101101;
            6: leds = 7'b1111101;
            7: leds = 7'b0000111;
            8: leds = 7'b1111111;
            9: leds = 7'b1100111;
            10: leds = 7'b1110111;
            11: leds = 7'b1111100;
            12: leds = 7'b0111001;
            13: leds = 7'b1011110;
            14: leds = 7'b1111001;
            15: leds = 7'b1110001;
    endcase
end
    
assign segments = ~leds;

endmodule 


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module Counter_16B(input CLOCK_1, //1KHz clock
                         output wire[15:0] count);
    
    reg [15:0] r_reg;
    wire [15:0] r_next;
    
    initial 
    begin 
        r_reg = 0; 
    end
    
    always @(posedge CLOCK_1)
    begin
        r_reg <= r_next;
    end
    
    assign count = r_reg;
    assign r_next = r_reg + 1;
    

endmodule 


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module One_KHz_Clock(input CLOCK_50, //50MHz clock signal
                            output reg CLOCK_1);
                            
    reg[27:0] counter = 28'd0;
    parameter divisor = 28'd50000;
    
    always@(posedge CLOCK_50)
    begin
        counter <= counter + 28'd1;
        if(counter >= (divisor - 1))
            counter <= 28'd0;
        CLOCK_1 <= (counter < divisor/2)?1'b1:1'b0;
    end
    
endmodule
```

Comment: Hint: `count` is not defined as 16-bits in all places it is defined

Answer (score 0):

The count variable needs to be a vector [15:0] was one bit.
Verified using a small testbench.
The design counts now.

```
module IO_Test3(

input                   CLK50,
    output [6:0]            HEX0,
    output [6:0]            HEX1,
    output [6:0]            HEX2,
    output [6:0]            HEX3
); 

    wire CLOCK1;
  wire [15:0] count; 
    

    One_KHz_Clock clock(CLK50, CLOCK1);
    
    Counter_16B counter(CLOCK1, count);
    
    Display_Driver_SevenSeg display(CLOCK1,count,HEX0,HEX1,HEX2,HEX3);
    
endmodule 


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


module Display_Driver_SevenSeg(
    
    input                      CLOCK_1, // 1KHz clock
    input wire  [15:0]         count,      //16 bit register
    output wire [6:0]           HEX0,
    output wire [6:0]           HEX1,
    output wire [6:0]           HEX2,
    output wire [6:0]           HEX3
);

    reg[15:0]       counter; 

    always@(*)
    begin
        counter = count;
    end
    
seg7 Dig0(counter[3:0], HEX0);
seg7 Dig1(counter[7:4], HEX1);
seg7 Dig2(counter[11:8], HEX2);
seg7 Dig3(counter[15:12], HEX3);

endmodule


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module seg7(input [3:0] hex, output wire [6:0] segments);

reg[6:0] leds;

always @(*) begin
    case (hex)
            0: leds = 7'b0111111;
            1: leds = 7'b0000110;
            2: leds = 7'b1011011;
            3: leds = 7'b1001111;
            4: leds = 7'b1100110;
            5: leds = 7'b1101101;
            6: leds = 7'b1111101;
            7: leds = 7'b0000111;
            8: leds = 7'b1111111;
            9: leds = 7'b1100111;
            10: leds = 7'b1110111;
            11: leds = 7'b1111100;
            12: leds = 7'b0111001;
            13: leds = 7'b1011110;
            14: leds = 7'b1111001;
            15: leds = 7'b1110001;
    endcase
end
    
assign segments = ~leds;

endmodule 


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module Counter_16B(input CLOCK_1, //1KHz clock
                         output wire[15:0] count);
    
    reg [15:0] r_reg;
    wire [15:0] r_next;
    
    initial 
    begin 
        r_reg = 0; 
    end
    
    always @(posedge CLOCK_1)
    begin
        r_reg <= r_next;
    end
    
    assign count = r_reg;
    assign r_next = r_reg + 1;
    

endmodule 


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module One_KHz_Clock(input CLOCK_50, //50MHz clock signal
                            output reg CLOCK_1);
                            
    reg[27:0] counter = 28'd0;
    parameter divisor = 28'd5;
  
    always@(posedge CLOCK_50)
    begin
        counter <= counter + 28'd1;
        if(counter >= (divisor - 1))
            counter <= 28'd0;
        CLOCK_1 <= (counter < divisor/2)?1'b1:1'b0;
    end

    
endmodule
```

Here is the SV testbench (runs on edaplayground.com):

```
module tb ();

  bit                    CLK50;
  logic [6:0]            HEX0;
  logic [6:0]            HEX1;
  logic [6:0]            HEX2;
  logic [6:0]            HEX3  ;
  
  always
    #5 CLK50 = ! CLK50;
  
  initial
    begin
    #10000;
    $finish;
    end
  
  initial
    begin
      $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); 
      $dumpvars;
    end
  
  IO_Test3
  u1(.*);
  
endmodule
```